# Audio Latency -Java program to Android program

Tags: java, android, audio

i have two Java Thread, one one my computer and the other one on a Android's phone. I want to stream the audio got from an audio line on my computer to the Android's phone, through UDP packets (peer to peer connection).

Everything works fine except for sometimes when the audio lag and the main problem that i have is the latency. I have tried differents sample frequencyes and differents buffer size but i still have latency (1-2 seconds) between the two devices.

That's my code.

**Java Audio Sender**

```
(new Thread(() -> {

            while (true) {
                   System.out.println(">>"+status);
                while (status) {

                    try {

                        int size = tdl.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        if(size>0){
                        DatagramPacket sendPacket
                                = new DatagramPacket(buffer, size, hostAddress, port);
                        socket.send(sendPacket);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AudioSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException ne) {

                    }
                }
            }

        })).start();

 public static void setUpAudioDriverInput() throws LineUnavailableException {
    if (tdl != null) {
        tdl.close();
    }

    int channels = 1;
    int sampleSize = 16;
    boolean bigEndian = false;

    format = new AudioFormat(rate, sampleSize, channels, true, bigEndian);

    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfoFinal.get(lineIndex));

    tdl = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(info);
    tdl.open(format);
    tdl.start();

}
```

**Java Android Audio Receiver**

```
  public void getStreaming(){


       getThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                System.out.println("Thread Streamer is Starting..  status2"+ status2);

                int rate = Integer.parseInt(((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.rateSpinner)).getSelectedItem().toString());
                int bufferSize = Integer.parseInt(((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bufferSizeSpinner)).getSelectedItem().toString());

                String payload = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText)).getText().toString();
                payload += "#" + rate;
                payload += "#" + bufferSize;
                payload += "#";

                System.out.println(">>>"+payload);

                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipAddressEditText)).getText().toString());
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(payload.getBytes(),payload.length(),address,8088);
                socket.send(dp);

               byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, rate, channelConfigOUT, audioFormat, buffer.length, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                audioTrack.play();


                DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

                System.out.println("BufferSize "+ bufferSize);




                boolean skip=false;

                while(status2 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    try {
                        socket.receive(receivedPacket);
                    }catch(SocketTimeoutException ste){
                        skip=true;
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        stopStreaming();

                    }
                    if(!skip) {
                        buffer = receivedPacket.getData();
                        audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        System.out.println("aaa" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

                    }
                }

            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });

    getThread.start();

}
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I found out that it was the network where i was trying that it was super forwarding the packets. With another network the latency really decreased up to less than half of a second. Yesterday i could watch a movie with it and the latency is at the limit. I will let you know if i will improve the system.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the TargetDataLine read size to create DatagramPacket.
Too many packet are created.

The best is to read some kilobytes of data (ie multiple tdl reads) and then send them in one "big" DatagramPacket.

Comment: For this i have a buffer no? If i set the buffer size to for example 4K or even more then i have less datagrams but more Latency. I have to minimize the latency.

Comment: Do not rely on your TargetDataLine to fill your buffer, read "small" data and send "big" UDP packets. If you use packets corresponding to ~200ms (8KB or 16KB depending of your audio setup), you will not notice the latency. My network audio devices are using such packet size.

Comment: Ok but again, what you are saying is like to have a buffer with specific size to contain 200ms of audio no? Then i would have still the same problem.

Comment: To be more precise : your final latency is : server capture latency + network latency + client processing. Capturing 200ms of audio will not end with the 1-2 second latency you are facing. The issue I see from your implementation (based on my own experience) is that your code is coupling capturing size and network size. You must adjust them independently. Be aware you are not free to capturing audio (TargetDataLine reads) with the buffer you "want" ( javadoc  : "Applications that record audio should read data from the target data line quickly enough to keep the buffer from overflowing") .

Comment: is coupling capturing size and network size'  . What do you mean? I tried different buffer size but i still get the delay. I also calculated how much time the tdl line takes to read datas and save them in the buffer and i got 0 ms.

Comment: I mean you are using the result of tdl.read(..) to create your UDP packet. Use a different buffer, one smal you tdl.read, one bigger for udp. In practive, it means "loop tdl.read until you big buffer is full, then send the big buffer".

Comment: I am doing like you said
int size = tdl.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length); if (size > 0) {
for(int i=0;i<tempBuffer.length;i++){
buffer[i+(tempBuffer.length*counter)]=tempBuffer[i];}
counter++;
 if(counter==63){
 DatagramPacket sendPacket
  = new DatagramPacket(buffer, bufferSize, hostAddress, port);
                                socket.send(sendPacket);
                                tempBuffer = new byte[bufferSize/4];
                                counter=0;
                                }

Comment: Ok i changed the network, and the latency now is smaller (half a second). Is it good? The network where i worked before was really old.